# How can we train tesseract (ver 4.1) for additional special characters ( like the division symbol "÷" )

Tags: unity-game-engine, ocr, tesseract

I am trying to train tesseract for recognizing additional special characters ( like the division symbol "÷" ). [ I am not trying to train it for a new font, just some additional characters ].
I am using Tesseract version 4.1, with Unity3D. At present, tesseract recognizes the division symbol ("÷") as addition symbol ("+"). I want to use use both these symbols together. But i can't find any way to train tesseract for recognizing it. 
I already have a eng.traineddata file working perfectly fine. It would be great if this file could be somehow modified to add support for division symbol as well.

[ Not sure if this matters or not, but in tesseract version 4.x, Whitelisting isn't supported. Also, the desired_characters file in LangData doesn't has the "÷" symbol
https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/langdata_lstm/tree/master/eng ]

- If it is not possible to extend a traineddata file for additional characters, is it possible to achieve support for the division symbol via training for a new font approach ?

Any suggestions are most welcome :)

Thanks

Comment: did you read docs?: https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/TrainingTesseract-4.00.html#fine-tuning-for--a-few-characters

Comment: this section looks helpful, guess i overlooked it. Thanks for the comment!